# Thunderbird new email count not displayed in 13.04

Tags: launcher, 13.04, thunderbird

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, Thunderbird (17.0.5) no longer displays the number of new emails in the Launcher.

The notification menu still displays as the emails come in, but there is no persistent number which appeared in a white circle on the launcher in 12.10.

Does anyone know how to get this back?

Comment: Same problem here. This issue seems to be kind of random on my end. Sometimes the number appears and sometimes it doesn't. Also, sometimes the little envelope icon in the top bar gets blue and sometimes it doesn't. If both happens I don't notice incoming mail which is really annoying.